# Can a response from an http request alter the base address in the next client request?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I have an octoprint server running at http://192.168.1.205.  I also have an nginx server hosting myDomain.  I want to be able to use the nginx server to pass on a request for `http://myDomain/octo` to http://192.168.1.205 using a reverse proxy.  Here is my nginx code...

```
server {
  server_name myDomain;
  location /octo/ {
    rewrite ^/octo/(.*) /$1 break;  #strip /octo from url
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.205;
  }
}
```

The first `http://myDomain/octo` request is passed on to `http://192.168.1.205` correctly.  But after the first response the code in the client makes another request to `http://myDomain/moreUri`. Since this uri doesn't have `/octo` nginx doesn't know to send it to `http://192.168.1.205/moreUri`.  Is there a way to have nginx change something in the first response so that the client then makes following requests to `http://myDomain/octo/moreUri`?

I was able to accomplish this for a case where the octoprint server responded with a redirect.  I used ...

```
proxy_redirect http://192.168.1.205/ http://myDomain/octo/;
```

and it worked.  But that only works on redirects and the following requests were wrong again.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have nginx change something in the first response so
> that the client then makes following requests to
> http://myDomain/octo/moreUri?

I am not aware that this is possible.

What about to adjust the nginx configuration accordingly ? using `location /` to process all requests within that block and add an additional `redirect` directive to address the "Since this uri doesn't have /octo nginx doesn't know to send it to [http://192.168.1.205/moreUri"](http://192.168.1.205/moreUri%22) should do the trick.

```
server {
  server_name myDomain;
  location / {
    rewrite ^/octo/(.*) /$1 break;  #strip /octo from url
    rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*) /octo/$2 break;  #rewrite /moreURI to /octo/moreURI
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.205;
  }
}
```

No matter if the above nginx reconfiguration fixes your issue, i assume the root cause why you need to configure the nginx as reverse proxy in this way might be a misconfigured (or not optimally configured) application. Check the config file if it is possible to configure the applications base path. If so, set it to `/octo/` (so the application itself prepends `/octo/` to all the links it presents to the user and all requests to the backend automatically) and adjust the rewrite rules accordingly.

Comment: In general that fix would be insufficient.  My stupid router will only handle one domain that can be used inside and outside the house (long story).  I have a number of apps, not just this octoprint, so using a rewrite of .*/.* wouldn't work for multiple apps.  I will check to see if octoprint can have a different base url.  Having said all this, if no one comes up with a better fix I'll give you the bounty (it is my choice, right?).

Comment: Please check https://docs.octoprint.org/en/master/configuration/config_yaml.html#server. The `reverseProxy` section in octoprint config looks very promising. Adding directive `add_header X-Script-Name /octo` and only have one rewrite rule `rewrite ^/octo/(.*) /$1 break;` in nginx config section for octo should already solve your issue.

Comment: That looks great.  I hadn't investigated it, I stupidly thought it wouldn't be possible.  I shouldn't sell such good software short.